# Android SQLite error using cordova

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite

I create the database and create the tables that are in it.  I print them all out with the following code

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT name from sqlite_master where type='table'", [], function(tx, result) {
    var len = result.rows.length;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {                      
       console.log(JSON.stringify(result.rows.item(i)));
    }
});
```

it prints it out and all tables are accounted for.

```
I/chromium(10913): [INFO:CONSOLE(766)] "{"name":"my_profile"}", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js (766)
```

the other tables seem to be working fine, its just this one, which i create last.

and i get this error

```
E/SQLiteLog(10913): (1) no such table: my_profile
W/System.err(10913): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such        table: my_profile (code 1): , while compiling: insert into $
W/System.err(10913):    at    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native  Method)
W/System.err(10913):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
W/System.err(10913):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
W/System.err(10913):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
W/System.err(10913):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
W/System.err(10913):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
W/System.err(10913):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1118)
W/System.err(10913):    at io.sqlc.SQLiteAndroidDatabase.executeSqlBatch(SQLiteAndroidDatabase.java:162)
W/System.err(10913):    at io.sqlc.SQLitePlugin$DBRunner.run(SQLitePlugin.java:354)
W/System.err(10913):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err(10913):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err(10913):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is on my Samsung S4, connected via usb

** special note, it works perfectly fine on the emulator.

Comment: while I'm not sure exactly how this was fixed because I changed the code around.  It does appear to be something to do with transactions.